# gameobjects on switch statement(col.tag)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im developing a game right now. It seems more like capture the flag in 2d. But im having problem with my character script. what i want is if my character has the flag and he goes back to her base with a flag(gameobject on) she will go to the winscene. but the thing is i also want her to not proceed to the winscene when the gameobject is not on.

Here's the Script

```
GameObject[] toEnable, toDisable;

public GameObject CharFlag;   
private Rigidbody2D rb;
private Animator anim;
private float moveSpeed;
private float dirX;
private bool facingRight = true;
private Vector3 localScale;


//Use this for Initialization
private void Start(){
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    localScale = transform.localScale;
    moveSpeed = 5f;

    // Finding game objects with tags "ToEnable" and "ToDisable"
    toEnable = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("CharFlag");


    // Disabling game objects with tag "ToEnable"
    foreach (GameObject element in toEnable)
    {
        element.gameObject.SetActive (false);
    }



}   

//Update is called once per frame
private void Update()
{
    dirX = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") * moveSpeed;

    if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown ("Jump") && rb.velocity.y == 0)
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * 700f);

    if (Mathf.Abs(dirX) > 0 && rb.velocity.y == 0)
        anim.SetBool("isRunning", true);
    else
        anim.SetBool("isRunning", false);

    if (rb.velocity.y == 0) 
    {
        anim.SetBool("isJumping", false);
        anim.SetBool("isFalling", false);
    }

    if (rb.velocity.y > 0) 
    {
        anim.SetBool("isJumping", true);
    }

    if (rb.velocity.y < 0) 
    {
        anim.SetBool("isJumping", false);
        anim.SetBool("isFalling", true);
    }

}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX, rb.velocity.y);
}

private void LateUpdate()
{
    if (dirX > 0)
        facingRight = true;
    else if (dirX < 0)
        facingRight = false;

    if (((facingRight) && (localScale.x < 0)) || ((!facingRight) && (localScale.x > 0)))
        localScale.x *= -1;

    transform.localScale = localScale;
}



void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D col)
{
    switch (col.tag) {

    case "EnemyField":
        CharFlag.gameObject.SetActive (true);
        break;

    case "AlyField":
        SceneManager.LoadScene ("YouWin");
        break;
}

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This would be better as a comment but I only have 40 reputation.

Simply check if the GameObject is active or not.

```
switch (col.tag) 
{
case "EnemyField":
    CharFlag.gameObject.SetActive (true);
    break;

case "AllyField":
    if(CharFlag.gameObject.activeSelf)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene ("YouWin");
    }

    break;
```

Comment: what does this error means?

Assets/Script/Character.cs(100,3): error CS8070: Control cannot fall out of switch statement through final case label `case "AllyField":'

Comment: My bad, the break should be outside the if statement